# Does the Li-F cell possess the highest possible voltage?

Tags: electrochemistry

My question is quite straightforward: would a theoretical cell with fluorine and lithium yield the highest possible standard potential of all?

The table of Standard electrode potential in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)) lists several potentials that are "better" than those of lithium and fluorine but I am skeptical about those values. The more common [tables](https://chem.libretexts.org/Ancillary_Materials/Reference/Reference_Tables/Electrochemistry_Tables/P2%3A_Standard_Reduction_Potentials_by_Value) often list lithium with a potential of -3.040 volts and fluorine with a potential of 3.053 volts. Thus the standard potential gives 6.093 volts. However, can this number be improved? Are there materials that have more negative potentials than lithium or a higher potential than fluorine?

Please ignore the cost of the cell or practically.

Comment: See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/102502/what-is-the-strongest-oxidising-agent which is all but a duplicate of this. It gives an example of a theoretical cell with a potential of a bit over 2,000,000 Volts.

Comment: Be aware that standard electrode potentials are thermodynamicaly equivalents of standard Gibbs energy of reaction a ox + b H2(g) <=> 2b H+(aq) +  a red as Delta G_r = -nF E_std.. Some of them are  just theoretical, with limited or hypothetical possibility to be directly measured, or to design a cell based on it. Note that above potentials are defined for water based solutions and hydrated Li+ and F-, what would definitely not be the case if such a cell were ever designed.